# expo and react navigation deep links in dev environment - what am I donig wrong?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo, deep-linking

I'm trying to get a webview to redirect to a different screen once a user clicks on a link in the webview/iframe.

Screens.js

```
const AppStack = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Ritual: {
      screen: RitualScreen,
    },
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
    },
    NewsFeed: {
      screen: WallScreen,
      path: 'newsfeed'
    }...


const AppContainer = createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
      App: {screen: AppStack, path: 'home'},
      Auth: AuthStack
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
    }
  )
);

export default AppContainer;
```

and then on the `RitualScreen` which is the page that loads when the app loads.. a survey is loaded in a webview. When the user clicks the `FINISH` link I want the user to be redirected to the newsfeed for example: I thought this was:

`exp://localhost:19000/home/newsfeed` - but any path aside from an empty one(exp://localhost:19000) just breaks..  What am I missing?

I know that in production I would need to change the domain to my scheme like myapp://
or use the linking method which auto changes the prefix in the uri.

But right now I just want to get this working in a dev environment.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a work around - although it's disgustingly cheeky, haha

Screen that renders Webview...

```
 20   render() {
 21     return (
 22       
 32       <WebView
 33         onNavigationStateChange={ 
             (e) => { 
               if(e.url == "https://www.google.com/") this.props.navigation.navigate("NewsFeed")
             }
          }
 34       source={{ uri: 'https://s.surveyanyplace.com/a-path-to-load' }} style={styles.WebView} />
 37     )
 38   };
 39 }
```

So essentially catching a redirect to a specific path before it's about to happen and using react navigator to go to a screen within the app in stead.